# Android Google Maps V2, how to get current location by gps/internet

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, maps

Here I am getting the location, by writing hardcoded latitude and longitude. I used `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`, it gives me the current location in map. But I also want marker to reach upto the my current location. 
Can you help to get latitude and longitude of my current position.

```
private final LatLng LOCATION = new LatLng(22.7515085,  75.8860726);

map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION).title("It is my current position"));

CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION, 6);

map.animateCamera(update);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Refer http://javapapers.com/android/markersgoogle-maps-android-api-v2/